# Linking iOS application to database

Tags: objective-c, ios, sql, database

Needed some advice as i am writing my first iOS application, 
1. what is the best way(simplest) to link an app to a database and does the database have to be SQLite (the databse will be external ie. linked via the internet)? i have used mySQL before in MAMP,

1. I have read up on other post and they suggest complicated methods like via JSON etc, please provide a simple way and a book/guide/web site that could teach me your suggested method would be much appreciated too :)

Comment: Whatever you want, just google through and you will get. Try to implemnt and if you stuck, we are here to solve and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is generally used for a local database (aka, on the device itself) through CoreData. But it seems like you have a remote MySQL database you want to connect to.

You should build some API that your iOS app talks to to get data from a database. Typically this is done over http which generates JSON in whatever server language of your choice (eg - python, ruby, php, etc).

For the iOS side, you'll probably use Apple's builtin features: [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is one of them.

However if your requirement is to share the database, you can go with mySQL or even Oracle etc.

JSON, xml are the tools that will help you to make a client server application.

Useful link:

http://jainmarket.blogspot.in/2009/05/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from.html